# Simple example application of Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions to minimization problem

Tags: reference-request, optimization, convergence-divergence, nonlinear-optimization, computer-algebra-systems

I am wondering if there is a simple example application of the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions to show that a minimum exists for a multivariate minimization/optimization problem.  Could anyone suggest a good reference textbook or monograph with an example?

Moreover, I am wondering if there is a computer algebra system (CAS) program or function that can be used to experiment with multivariate equations.  The input to the program would be a multivariate equation, whereas the output would be some sort of analytic check for convergence (i.e. that a minimum exists).  Perhaps such a program would quickly help to check equations for convergence.

Comment: The KKT conditions are necessary conditions, just like Lagrange multipliers. Generally they cannot be used to show that a minimum exists unless you know something more about the problem (convexity, for example).

Comment: @copper.hat: Thanks, copper.hat.  Is there a good expository reference that deals with the KKT conditions, and perhaps demonstrates how to use them?  How do I show convexity?

Comment: This is a tough one for me. Frankly, it took me a long time to grasp the KKT conditions (and similar), and it wasn't until I acquired some familiarity with nonsmooth analysis (Frank Clarke, "Optimization and Nonsmooth Analysis") in the context of minimax problems ($\min_x \max_i f_i(x)$) that I began to get a grip on understanding. However, that is a tough route to follow, if understanding KKT is your goal. I have only glanced at the book, but Boyd & Vandenberghe's "Convex Optimization" has a section on KKT for convex problems, which might be good to develop intuition.

Comment: Oh, these references are just lovely, and the Boyd & Vandenberghe book is available online as well: http://www.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/, so I can read it immediately.  Please write this up as an answer.

Comment: You are welcome, hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the answer is late, but maybe it can help others with the same problem.

When I needed to understand the KKT conditions, [this explanation](http://www.onmyphd.com/?p=kkt.karush.kuhn.tucker) helped me a lot, with a very simple and complete step by step example. If it is still complicated, I recommend [reading this chapter](https://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9780387895512-c1.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-807804-p173924715) from [Mathematial Optimization and Economic Analysis (Luptácik, M.; Springer)](https://www.springer.com/la/book/9780387895512) on the subject carefully. When you master the basics concepts, you can already go to practically any book or handbook on nonlinear optimization.